# Error using Twitter gem, Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-gem

I am getting this error on my Heroku deployment:

```
Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT: Address family not supported by protocol - 
socket2 
        usrruby19.2libruby1.9.1nethttprb:644:in initialize 
        usrruby19.2libruby1.9.1nethttprb:644:in open 
        usrruby19.2libruby1.9.1nethttprb:644:in block in connect 
        usrruby19.2libruby1.9.1timeoutrb:44:in timeout
```

When I make a certain call Twitter like so:

```
Twitter.profile_image('screen name', :size => 'mini')
```

This code works locally as per the gem's documentation and I've not 
been able to Google anything about it.

My local setup is as follows:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10.6.0], MBARI 
0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03
```

And I am using the bamboo-mri-1.9.2 stack on Heroku.

Comment: why are you using 1.8.7 locally and 1.9.2 on heroku?  have you tried changing your heroku stack to 1.8.7?

Comment: @Will I changed my Heroku stack to 1.8.7 as you said but no dice. However, I did disable the use of Apigee, which worked. So I believe that the Twitter gem may not fully support Apigee. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

**Address family not supported by protocol - socket(2) (Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT)** this error has no other better solution than time.In realit the socket is already in a running state so unless and unrtil it gets free there is no solution to it.Then also you can try by restarting your machine.

Comment: can you explain more. maybe a program to reproduce the error ?